# Mongoose.js ignoring default value in subdoc Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently writing a web app with mongodb and mongoose. I defined a document schema, that has has an array of subdocuments. I defined the subdocs in a different Schema. The subdocuments have fields with default values, for example: `end: {type: Date, default: Date.now}`. Unfortunately on creating the parent doc with some subdocs only the fields of the subdoc are set which I set explicitly. It seems that mongoose is ignoring the `default` option.

Do you guys have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

*employment.model.js*

```
var Shift = require('./shift.model.js').ShiftSchema;

var EmploymentSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    ....
    shifts: [Shift]
});
```

*shift.model.js*

```
var ShiftSchema = new Schema({
   title: {type: String},
   ....
   info: {type:String, default: 'Hallo'},
   start: {type: Date, default: Date.now, index: true},
   end: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
module.exports.ShiftSchema = ShiftSchema;
module.exports = mongoose.model('Shift', ShiftSchema);
```

None of the above `default` values are set.
My mongoose.js version is: `~3.8.8`

*Sample Shift Creation*

```
Employment.create({
    title: 'PopulateDB Employ',
    start: new Date(),
    customer: result.customer,
    shifts: [{
      title: 'Shift 1',
      start: new Date()
    },{
      title: 'Shift 2',
      start: new Date()
    }]
  },cb)
```

Comment: additionally my subdocs don't have id fields.... I am pretty helpless right now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your export of `ShiftSchema` with the next statement that assigns the model as the only export of the module.  The result is that `Shift` is ending up as `undefined` in *employment.model.js*.

Change the first line of that file to the following to access the schema from the exported model:

```
var Shift = require('./shift.model.js').schema;
```

and just remove the `module.exports.ShiftSchema = ShiftSchema;` line in *shift.model.js*.